# 32 bit int shifted by an amount not in the range

Tags: java

I know there is a missing cast to long, but is there a better way to do this which is less confusing than the shown approch.

```
static long getLong(byte[] sourceBytes, int sourceBytesIndex, int numOfBytesToConvert)
{
    long longValue = 0;

    longValue = (sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex] & 0xFF) +
                         ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 1] & 0xFF) << 8);

    if (numOfBytesToConvert > 2)
    {
        longValue += ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 2] & 0xFF) << 16) +
                                ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 3] & 0xFF) << 24);

        if (numOfBytesToConvert > 4)
        {
            longValue += ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 4] & 0xFF) << 32) +
                                    ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 5] & 0xFF) << 40);

            if (numOfBytesToConvert > 6)
            {
                longValue += ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 6] & 0xFF) << 48) +
                                        ((sourceBytes[sourceBytesIndex + 7] & 0xFF) << 56);
            }
        }
    }

    return longValue;
}
```

Comment: How about a simple loop?

Comment: BTW: Using `& 0xFFL` instead of `& 0xFF` will give you `long` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use ByteBuffers, you can also use a switch statement.

```
static long getLong(ByteBuffer bb, int numOfBytesToConvert) {
    switch (numOfBytesToConvert) {
        case 8:
            return bb.getLong();
        case 6:
            long aChar = bb.getChar();
            long anInt = bb.getInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            return bb.order() == ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN
                    ? aChar << 32 + anInt
                    : anInt << 16 + aChar;
        case 4:
            return bb.getInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
        case 2:
            return bb.getChar();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

The ByteBuffer handles both byte endianess as well the position and the end of usable bytes in the buffer. (Using limit())

I tend to prefer direct ByteBuffers as there can be large without using much heap and are faster than a `byte[]` when using the native byte order.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
long value = new BigInteger(sourceBytes).longValue();
```

---

```
static long getLong(byte[] sourceBytes, int sourceBytesIndex, int numOfBytesToConvert) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytesToConvert];
   System.arraycopy(sourceBytes, sourceBytesIndex, bytes, 0, numOfBytesToConvert);
   return new BigInteger(sourceBytes).longValue();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the `sourceBytesIndex` and `numOfBytesToConvert` are important. ;)

Comment: I remember, I once heard of a `System.arraycopy` function. If it still exists (its pretty old), then it could help ;)

Comment: Along with creating a new byte[], it could help, except BigInteger only takes one byte order, big endian, so a loop might be a better choice. (; the example is little endian. ;)

Comment: Correct, the byte array needs to have long values in *big-endian* byte order. (which actually is the case for this question)